# Show $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

So we know this is Cauchy because the sequence converges to 1. 
Now, to show it is Cauchy:
$$|x_j - x_k| \leq \frac{1}{n} \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ given } j,k \geq m$$

We know $|x_k - x_k| = |\frac{j}{j+1}- \frac{k}{k+1}| \leq |\frac{j}{j+1}| + |\frac{k}{k+1}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$

So really we can say $\frac{j}{j+1},\frac{k}{k+1} < \frac{1}{2n}$
Now to find $m$ we need to solve for $j$ or $k$.

We have, $$\frac{k}{k+1} = \frac{1}{2n}$$

$$\implies k= \frac{1}{2n-1}$$ So let m = $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ then $k,j > \frac{1}{2n-1}$ and $0 < \frac{k}{k+1},\frac{j}{j+1} < \frac{1}{2n-1}$

$$\frac{1}{n} > \frac{k}{k+1}+\frac{j}{j+1} \geq |\frac{k}{k+1}| + |\frac{j}{j+1}| \geq |\frac{k}{k+1} - \frac{j}{j+1}|$$

So really I am asking for help because I want to know if my approach works or not. I know there are other ways to approach the problem and get a solution. Is this a valid solution? I am missing a step or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach has problems.  For example the inequality $$|\frac{j}{j+1}| + |\frac{k}{k+1}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

is not valid for large values of $j$ and $k$

You may try  the following approach.
$$|\frac {m}{m+1} - \frac {n}{n+1}|= \frac {|m-n|}{(m+1)(n+1)}\le$$

$$\frac {m}{mn}=\frac {1}{n}$$

So you make the difference of terms less than $\epsilon$ if you choose  $m$ and $n$ larger than $\frac {1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: How did you get $\frac {m}{mn}=\frac {1}{n}$ from $|\frac {m}{m+1} - \frac {n}{n+1}|= \frac {|m-n|}{(m+1)(n+1)}$

Comment: $|m-n|<m $ and $(m+1)(n+1)>mn$ so the fraction is less than $\frac {m}{mn}=1/n$

Comment: How did you come up with that strategy? It seems like you were looking for a fraction that is larger than $ \frac {|m-n|}{(m+1)(n+1)}$ and that also approaches 0. Did you just use trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your approach. We would like to make $|x_j - x_k|$ arbitrarily close to zero. Although we have $|x_j - x_k| \leq |\frac{j}{j+1}| + |\frac{k}{k+1}|$, notice that we can't make this upper bound arbitrarily close to zero. The bound I think you want is $|x_j-x_k| \leq \frac{1}{j} + \frac{1}{k}$. Convince yourself that this is true. Now given $\epsilon > 0$, can you find a natural number $M$ such that this upper bound is less than $\epsilon$ for $j,k > M$?

Comment: Ideally I want:$\frac{k}{k+1} < \frac{1}{2n-1}$. So $\frac{k}{k+1} $ can be at most 1/2. But I think I meant to say $\frac{k}{k+1} < \frac{1}{2(2n-1)}$ since we have $\frac{k}{k+1}$ and $\frac{j}{j+1}$ Are the equalities not satisfiable if this is true?

Comment: The sequence $\frac{k}{k+1}$ converges to $1$ so it can't be at most $1/2$. Also the inequalities you've written can't be true in general. The sequences $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{2(2n-1)}$ both converge to $0$.

Comment: Okay that's obvious now. I guess I was wrong because I assumed $|\frac{j}{j+1}- \frac{k}{k+1}| = |\frac{j}{j+1}| + |\frac{k}{k+1}|$. I was trying to get $\frac{k}{k+1} < \frac{1}{2n}$. And I forgot that the point is to show that the difference approaches 0. Thanks!

Comment: So I think $|x_j-x_k| \leq \frac{1}{j} + \frac{1}{k}$ is true because $\frac{1}{j} + \frac{1}{k}$ approaches 0 but how do we know this is what we want from $|x_k - x_k| = |\frac{j}{j+1}- \frac{k}{k+1}| $

Answer (score 0):

Very simply,

$\begin{array}\\
|x_j - x_k| 
&= |\frac{j}{j+1}- \frac{k}{k+1}|\\
&= |(1-\frac{1}{j+1})- (1-\frac{1}{k+1})|\\
&= |-\frac{1}{j+1}+\frac{1}{k+1}|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{j+1}|+|\frac{1}{k+1}|\\
&\lt 2|\frac{1}{\min(j, k)}|\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } \min(j, k) \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

In general,
if $x_k \to L$
as $k \to \infty$,
then, for any $c > 0$,
there is an $n(c)$ such that
$|x_n-L| < c$
for $n > n(c)$.

Therefore,
for any $c > 0$,
for $j, k > n(c/2)$

$\begin{array}\\
|x_k - x_j| 
&= |(x_k-L)-(x_j-L)|\\
&\le |(x_k-L)|+|(x_j-L)|\\
&\lt (c/2)+c/2)\\
&= c\\
\text{so}\\
|x_k - x_j| 
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$